# Team Foundation build does not start and is still queued

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Somehow our TF builds stopped working. When triggered, the build stays within the queue and does nothing. The build was also triggered with high priority.

We have also checked the system events, but there are no TF related errors. We have also restarted the IIS site of the TFS - no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the build server? Or unregistering and then reregistering it?

Comment: Note: Your build server should not be installed on your TFS server

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already checked to make sure your build agent is running.  If so, there's a good chance you've run into a bug I've seen before.  If this is the case, do you have the latest updates for TFS?  If this is the bug I'm thinking about, it causes the build agent to appear "reserved" when it's not.  Getting the latest updates should address that particular issue.  I don't know what version of TFS and what updates you have.